# Write a function "giveMeRandom" which accepts a number n and returns an array containing n random numbers between 0 and 10

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to Write a function "giveMeRandom" which accepts a number n and returns an array containing n random numbers between 0 and 10

I can't push generate array of n (arg) length.
It generates only one.

```
const giveMeRandom = function(n) {
    let arrWithNums = [];
    for(i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        return arrWithNums.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)); 
    }
    return arrWithNums;
}
console.log(giveMeRandom(4));
```

Comment: Remove `.length` from the condition part of the loop (`n` is already a number), and also remove `return` from the body of the loop, (it finishes the entire function), then your function will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

n is a number which does not have a length. Just use following for loop:

`for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {...}`

Also remove the return statement inside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is `n.length`. The number `4` has a length of one, and if `i < 1` then the loop will not run at all. You just want `n` in this place instead.

The other problem is that you're returning a value at every repetition of the loop, which stops the function running. Only return a value once at the end to fix this problem.

Here's the full code:

```js
function giveMeRandom(n) {

    let arrWithNums = [];
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arrWithNums.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)); 
    }
    
    return arrWithNums;
}

console.log(giveMeRandom(4));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const giveMeRandom = function(n) {
  let arrWithNums = [];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   arrWithNums.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
  }
  return arrWithNums;
}
console.log(giveMeRandom(6));
```