# how to sum every number inside the th

Tags: javascript, html, dom-manipulation

I have a table with tr and th
I have  - with numbers values and with imgs inside;
I need to find sum of number values inside all th. 
This script does equal '0'. Where is the bug ??

```
 function sumOfTh(){
      let ths = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
      let res = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < ths.length; i++) {
        if (isNaN(ths[i].value)) {
          res += 0;
        } else {
          res += parseInt(ths[i].value);
        }
       return res;

      }
      console.log(res);


  }
```

Here is HTML

```
<table class="border" id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">1</th>
        <th><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_quiz.asp" ><img class="img" src="cell.jpg"></a></th>
        <th>3</th>
        <th><a href="https://www.testdome.com/tests/html-css-online-test/13"><img class="img" src="cell.jpg"></a></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>5</th>
        <th>6</th>
        <th>7</th>
        <th>8</th>
        <th>9</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
        <th>12</th>
        <th>13</th>
        <th>14</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>15</th>
        <th>16</th>
        <th>17</th>
        <th>18</th>
        <th>19</th>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: You're exiting the function on the first round of the loop. Move the return statement out of the body of the loop to the end of the body of the function. A regular `for ... loop` does not need `return`, unless you want to exit the function in the middle of the loop. This is almost a dup of [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61270662/write-a-function-givemerandom-which-accepts-a-number-n-and-returns-an-array-co).

Comment: `ths[i].value` will be undefined. Show some HTML please

Comment: here you go . .

Answer (score 1):

`ths[i].value` is undefined. What you're looking for is **textContent**.

Also you need to check that it's not NaN *and* not empty.

And you need to return outside of the loop. You're returning after the first iteration.

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/g3he2ts8/3/

```
function sumOfTh(){
    let ths = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
    let res = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < ths.length; i++) {
        let content = ths[i].textContent;
        if (!isNaN(content) && content !== '') {
            res += parseInt(content);
        } 
    }
    console.log(res); 
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the return statement down, then it should work

```
function sumOfTh(){
    let ths = document.getElementsByTagName('th');
    let res = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ths.length; i++) {
        if (isNaN(ths[i].value)) {
            res += 0;
        } else {
            res += parseInt(ths[i].value);
        } 
    }
    console.log(res); 
    return res;
}
```